# Silverlight WCF RIA - Authentication Timeout

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have some issues about SL authetentication.

I am using WCF RIA Services to get access to database and implement authentication and reading/writing data to database. Now, I have custom Authentication Service and custom Role Provider (coz without last database returns exception). In the Roles Provider class I implemented only one method "**IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)**". I do not know why, but all other methods are not used by project.

**1.** At **web.config** file I have a next text about authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" timeout="1440"/>
</authentication>
```

I set timeout 1440 (also authentication cookies have an expiration date to +30 days). But anyway, the application lost authentication in *6-7 minutes of idle*. **Why???** Also I didn't find any similar preferences at hosting settings.

**2.** Now, by the Fiddler 2 I can see strange cookie settings (only when getting database information):

```
Set-Cookie: .ASPXROLES=; expires=Tue, 12-Oct-1999 04:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

I tried to find which class or method put this cookie, but I didn't find anything. Just like "phantom" cookies -_-... I think, it's one of my main troubles with authentication timeout. **What is it and how can I change it?**

**3.** I found good solution ([Silverlight RIA Services - How To Best Handle Client Auth Session Timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948685/silverlight-ria-services-how-to-best-handle-client-auth-session-timeout)) but It can help me only catch the exception. If I use next method:

```
WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoadUser(Application_UserLoaded, null);
```

In application startup, all seems okay and *User Identity* loads from cookies. But! If I will try to use this method after 6-7 min's of idle, the application IN A MAGIC WAY change navigation page to "LoginPage". I do not know and do not have any ideas HOW it does this. But it's true. I was at page "Desktop". Then I tried to "relog" user after idle, frame changing to different page and all data (from previously page) is LOST... :( So, **why the "LoadUser" method turns me on different page with Login Window, why it does not just relogin User Identity?**